# Implementing a context aware dialogue system

Tags: java, nlp, artificial-intelligence

Any help on designing an open domain context aware conversational system is appreciated. Any architecture, papers or available open source api's would suffice.

Basic idea is to maintain a stack of domains based on which the communication proceeds. Like If I am using the same as a QA system, if my area of question is Movie, the responses could be more tailor made to the movie domain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @beaker, that is true... but these kinds of questions too need a place. I don't think any one can post a code snippet for this. There have been quite a lot questions seeking research papers et al. If it were a basic homework question in java/cpp, then the question is not appreciated... but for wide domains like AI, I think this should be permitted.

Comment: @ArunAK I agree that it's a valid (and interesting) question, I just think it would be more appropriate, and get better answers, in another forum like cstheory. I didn't recommend one because I'm not certain where it would best fit. But the post has not been put on hold, so perhaps my opinion is in the minority.

Answer (score -1):

Plz have a look at these -

[Link 1](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Artificial_Intelligence/Natural_Language/Chatterbots/)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011699/latest-in-open-source-chatbot-fake-ai) (a related stackoverflow question)